# How to filter a column based on a condition from another column in R

Tags: r, vector, subset

I have a huge data table with millions of rows and dozens columns, so performance is a crucial issue for me. The data describes visits to a content site. I want to compute the ContentId of the earliest (i.e. minimum hit time) hit of each visit. What I did is:
    `dt[,.(FirstContentOfVisit=ContentID[ContentID != ""][which.min(HitTime)]), by=VisitId,.SDcols=c("ContentID","HitTime")]`

the problem is that I don't know if which.min first computes the min on all the HitTime vector (which I don't want!) or does it only on the filtered HitTime vector (the one which is corresponding to the non-empty ContentID).

In addition, after I compute it - how can I get the minimal HitTime of the ContentIDs that are different from the first (i.e. the earliest hit time of the non-first content id).

When I tried to have both actions with user-defined functions (first - sort the sub data table and then extract the desired value) it took ages (and actually never stopped), although I have a very strong machine (virtual) with 180 GB RAM. So I'm looking for an inline solution.

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` makes this much easier. You didn't share a sample of your data, but I assume the variables of interest look something like this.

```
web <- tibble(
  HitTime = sample(seq(as.Date('2010/01/01'), as.Date('2017/02/23'), by="day"), 1000),
  ContentID = 1:1000,
  SessionID = sample(1:100, 1000, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Then you can just use `group_by` and `summarise` to find the earliest value of `HitTime` for each `SessionID`.

```
web %>%
  group_by(SessionID) %>%
  summarise(HitTime = min(HitTime))
```